# Replace text string WITH a variable

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using an `.ahk` script for text replacement. So I use

```
::-h:: Hi, thanks for your mail
```

However, I would now like to include a variable. So I want to try to achieve:

- Press shk shortcut key (-h)
- Inputbox pops up / I insert variable (for example "marc"
- Ahk prints text including variable (for example, "Hi marc, thanks for your mail"

I tried to get this working by

```
::-h:: hi var1, thanks for your mail
var1 = inputbox("Insert Name")
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use an extra inputbox? You could have a much more comfortable solution if you used [Dynamic Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15015-regex-powered-dynamic-hotstrings/) instead. If we make a small change in the syntax, we can build a simple but powerful hotstring:

```
hotstrings("([a-zA-Z -]+)#h", "Hi %$1%, thanks for your mail")
```

Now if, you type something like `Marc#h`, it will automatically be replaced, without having to handle an ugly inputbox. This will also work for full names, e.g. `Marc Smith#h`. By using `#h` instead of `-h`, we're able to also type in double names: `Mary-Anne#h` will work just as  well as `Emma-Kate Smith-Jones#h`.

Comment: thanks MCL, this is exactly what im looking for. Only when i copy your code into my ahk document I get an error that it call to a non-existent function... Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @user181796 You have to include the library I linked.

Comment: sorry man, i dont understand. Kind of a newbie with the whole ahk thing. Do you have a link to a place where there a basic explanation of how all this works?

Comment: @user181796 First thing you should always do is search the [docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_Include.htm).

Comment: @user181796 Can you please remove your corresponding question on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
; SetKeyDelay, keyDelay:=250, pressDuration:=50
OnMessage(WM_LBUTTONDOWN:=0x201, "WndProc"), uStyle:=(WS_BORDER :=0x00800000)
                                                   +=(WS_CAPTION:=0x00C00000)
                                                   |=(WS_SIZEBOX:=0x00040000)

::-h::
   SetTimer, % "ChangeStyle", -50
   InputBox, outputVar
           ,, % "   enter something"
           ,, 125, 90
           , A_ScreenWidth/2-65
           , A_ScreenHeight/2-45
   IfNotEqual, ErrorLevel, 0, MsgBox, 262144, % A_Space, % "entry canceled", .75
   IfEqual, ErrorLevel, 0, SendEvent, % "{Raw}Hi "outputVar ", thanks for your mail"
   Return

ChangeStyle:
   WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, % "A"
   WinSet, Style, % "^"uStyle, % "A"
   Return

WndProc(aParams*)
{
   Static WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:=0x00A1, HTCAPTION:=2

   PostMessage, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION,,, % "ahk_id"aParams.4
}
```